# Which address to share with users, to give them access to a server application on a local network?

Tags: local-area-network

An application is supposed to function as a server on the local network. It displays its address visually, and users can enter them into their client applications (possibly on other machines on the local network), in order to connect to it. It is not required to work outside of the local network.

The purpose is that even if I use mDNS, there might be networks where it's not available, or when the server is running on multiple machines and the users would like to specify which one to connect to.

However, when my server sets up a TCP socket, I see multiple addresses. 
I use Qt's QNetworkInterface, which returns me the following addresses:

```
Listening at  "fe80::589c:xxxx:xxxx:65a5%ethernet_32770"
Listening at  "192.168.1.163"
Listening at  "::1"
Listening at  "2001:0:9d38:90d7:3ca4:xxxx:xxxx:fe5c"
Listening at  "fe80::3ca4:xxxx:xxxx:fe5c%tunnel_32768"
```

It seems obvious, that I can just display the IPV4 address, as that's the easiest for a user to write down and enter in the client application.

However, I'm afraid about how future-proof it is.

Answer (score 0):

Please configure a local dns entry for the server in your dhcp server which can be shared with your users.  This can be done by adding an entry in the /etc/host file of the dhcp server. This would remain future proof as any change in the server's ip address can be updated at one place.